# Passing 2 data from php to iMacros javascript, but 1 is missing

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

This is my php code:

```
$s = $iim1->iimSet("test1",$test1);
$s = $iim1->iimSet("test2",$test2);
$s = $iim1->iimPlay("test.js");
```

In javascript

```
var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=test.com" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_UserName CONTENT={{test1}}" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:Button_OK" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro)

var checking=iimGetLastExtract();

var macro1 = "CODE:";
if(checking=='hasuser'){
macro1 += "VERSION BUILD=10022823" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:set<SP>score" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_Password CONTENT={{test2}}" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:Button_OK" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro1)
}
```

When imacros performing to input password(it shows **undefined** ) in the text fill, as i know the test2 is empty because first macro has run.

So, how can i store the value of test2 to use it in the second macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it in JavaScript like so:

```
var macro = "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=8970419 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=test.com" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_UserName CONTENT={{test1}}" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:Button_OK" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H2 ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{test2}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro)

var checking=iimGetExtract(1);

var macro1 = "CODE:";
if(checking=='hasuser'){
macro1 += "VERSION BUILD=10022823" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:set<SP>score" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:txt_Password CONTENT=" + iimGetExtract(2) + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:Button_OK" + "\n";
macro1 += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:OK" + "\n";
iimPlay(macro1)
}
```